# In an AJAX update, how can I access code from an external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, simplemodal

I'm learning Ruby on Rails and I'd like to use some unobtrusive javascript to display a modal. When the user clicks on a remote link, it calls an action in one of my controllers that returns the following javascript...

```
var SM = new SimpleModal({"width":600});
SM.addButton("Action button", "btn primary", function(){
  this.hide();
});

SM.addButton("Cancel", "btn");
SM.show({
    "model":"modal-ajax",
    "title":"Title",
    "param":{
      "url":"/ajax/url",
      "onRequestComplete": function(){ /* Action on request complete */ }
    }
});
```

...but the problem is the code doesn't know what SimpleModal is since that's defined in a separate javascript file. How can I import or reference that SimpleModal code so that my AJAX update can create the SimpleModal object and show it?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 0):

Require Simple Modal in your application.js for application wide use

```
//= require simple_modal
```

Comment: I'm already doing that, but when debugging, it appears the unobtrusive javascript I posted in my question doesn't have access to the javascript files that are loaded into the page.

Comment: Are you sure your application.js loads first before your js code ?

Comment: Yes. The page is fully loaded before clicking the link that returns the unobtrusive JavaScript.